# How can I catch an invalid fgetpos call as a C++ exception on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, std, seh

In Visual C++ 2008, I want to "catch" an exception generated as shown here:

```
try {
    int foo = 20;
    ::fgetpos(0, (fpos_t*)&foo);
}
//...
```

Here are adjustments I've made to attempt a successful catch:

1. SEH is activated (/eha)
2. I've added a catch(...)
3. I've added a [_set_se_translator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) vector.
4. I've added/adjusted to SEH syntax: __try / __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)

In short, I've tried "everything in the book" and I still can't catch the exception.  If I replace the call to `::fgetpos` with `int hey = foo / 0` then suddenly all of the above techniques work as expected.  So the exception I'm dealing with from `::fgetpos` is somehow "extra special."

Can someone explain why this ::fgetpos error seems uncatchable, and how to work around it?

**update** When executed in the VS IDE, the output window doesn't name an exception.  All it says is this:

> Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in MyProgram.exe.

Not very helpful.  When I run the console app from the command line, I get a crash dialogue.  The "problem details" section of the dialogue includes this information:

> Problem Event Name:  BEX
>    Exception Offset:0002fd30
>    Exception Code:  c0000417
>    Exception Data:  00000000
>    Additional Information 1:69ad
>    Additional Information 2:69addfb19767b2221c8e3e7a5cd2f4ae
>    Additional Information 3:b1ff
>    Additional Information 4:b1ffca30cadddc78c19f19b6d150997f

Comment: Do try to not keep the exception type a secret.  Look in the Output window.

Comment: What exception?  Note that calling `::TerminateProcess()` is not an exception, even though both cause your program to quit.

Comment: @Ben: I did not know that ::TerminateProcess might be called by CRT routines without an attempt to seek an exception filter.

Comment: Can you step into the function with the debugger?

Comment: Exactly which error are you hoping to detect? The one coming from passing in a null stream pointer? Or the one coming from passing an `int*` to a function that expects a pointer to an `fpos_t` instead?

Comment: I think you can get a better grasp of the problem by enabling first-chance exception catch in Visual Studio, so you can see in the CRT code the line where the exception is generate and (stepping) the exception handler that catches it.

Comment: @Brent: While `fgetpos` is probably not calling `::TerminateProcess` directly, if it detects an error it's not going to generate an exception.  That's not the C way of doing things.  To handle errors in CRT functions, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb.aspx

Comment: Have you considered the better solution:  just don't pass invalid arguments to the library function?  :-|

Comment: @Matteo: Unfortunately, activating the "first-chance" code breaks did not change the outcome.  I always receive a dialogue box instead of something I can capture.

Comment: @Brent Arias: then maybe there's an assertion in the CRT for that invalid value, that, if it fails, doesn't raise an exception but just terminates the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code in your dump corresponds to `STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER`, try [`_set_invalid_parameter_handler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb.aspx)

Comment: Hey!!! How did you lookup that error code?  The "error lookup" in visual studio didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: It seems this handler let's me do logging, but does not allow me to recover from the failure. :(

Comment: I spoke too soon.  When this handler is 'set', it causes fgetpos to return an error code rather than causing my whole app to crash.  Ok, I guess I got what I wanted - even if it is stranger than I'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the runtime catches it for you and issues a debug dialog without returning or propagating the exception- that is a CRT call and they may add whatever exception catching code in there they like. It's well within Visual Studio's rights to catch a hardware exception inside a library function, *especially* if you are running from within the IDE or in debug mode, then it is *expected* of the runtime.

Of course, when you divide by zero, then there is no library call here to write that extra catching code.